# Populating data in objectstore , delets data from other object store in IndexedDB

Tags: indexeddb

I need to create seven object stores in IndexedDB database.  I create them one by one and populate them after each creation transaction complete.  I populate each object store from ajax call returned data.

In end of JS execution, I can see all seven object stores created, but only last one has data in it. In debug mode, I observed that each one gets populated but at the same time, I do not know how the data from  previously populated object store gets deleted.

Thank you.
Nandita

Comment: You need to share some code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full javascript code :

```
function openAddressDB(){

if (!window.indexedDB) {
  window.alert("Your browser doesn't support a stable version of IndexedDB. Can't store address data in web storage");        
} else {
  // Let us open address database
  var request = window.indexedDB.open(Address_DB_Name, Address_DB_Version);

  //Sucess event handler
  request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    addressDb = request.result; 

    refreshAddressList();      

    // Generic error handler for all errors targeted at this database's requests!
    addressDb.onerror = function(event) {          
      alert(Address_DB_Name + " error: " + event.target.errorCode);
    };
  };

  // If some other tab is loaded with the database, then it needs to be closed
  // before we can proceed.
  request.onblocked = function(event) {  
    alert("Need to update "+Address_DB_Name+" database, please close all other tabs with this site open!");
  }; 

  //Error event handler
  request.onerror = function(event) {
     alert("Open "+Address_DB_Name+" failed:" + event.target.errorCode );
  };

  //upgrade event handler
  request.onupgradeneeded = function (evt) { 
    addressDb =  evt.currentTarget.result;

    //delete object store if database is upgrading
    if (event.oldVersion != 0){

      if(addressDb.objectStoreNames.contains(Address1_Store)) {
         addressDb.deleteObjectStore(Address1_Store);
      }

      if(addressDb.objectStoreNames.contains(Address2_Store)) {                     
        addressDb.deleteObjectStore(Address2_Store);
      }

      if(addressDb.objectStoreNames.contains(Address3_Store)) {
        addressDb.deleteObjectStore(Address3_Store);
      }
      if(addressDb.objectStoreNames.contains(Town_City_Store)) {
        addressDb.deleteObjectStore(Town_City_Store);
      }
      if(addressDb.objectStoreNames.contains(County_Store)) {
        addressDb.deleteObjectStore(County_Store);
      }
      if (addressDb.objectStoreNames.contains(State_Store)) {
       addressDb.deleteObjectStore(State_Store);
      }
      if  (addressDb.objectStoreNames.contains(Post_Code_Store)) {
       addressDb.deleteObjectStore(Post_Code_Store);
      }
      if  (addressDb.objectStoreNames.contains(Country_Store)) {
       addressDb.deleteObjectStore(Country_Store); 
      }
      if  (addressDb.objectStoreNames.contains(Region_Store)) {
       addressDb.deleteObjectStore(Region_Store);                      
      }
    }           

    //creating object store  and store data

    //Address 1               
    $("#addressview").find("[name='address1id']").each(function(index){ 
        address1Store =addressDb.createObjectStore(Address1_Store,{ keyPath: "id" });
        // Create an index to search on 
        address1Store.createIndex("parentAddressListValueId", "parentAddressListValueId", { unique: false });
        address1Store.transaction.oncomplete = function(event){                   
            loadAddressList('address1id', 'Address1')           
          };
    });      

    //Address 2
    $("#addressview").find("[name='address2id']").each(function(index){               
        address2Store =addressDb.createObjectStore(Address2_Store,{ keyPath: "id" });
        address2Store.createIndex("parentAddressListValueId", "parentAddressListValueId", { unique: false });
        address2Store.transaction.oncomplete = function(event){                     
            loadAddressList('address2id','Address2')           
          };
    }); 

   

    //Address 3
    $("#addressview").find("[name='address3id']").each(function(index){                    
      address3Store =addressDb.createObjectStore(Address3_Store,{ keyPath: "id" });
      address3Store.createIndex("parentAddressListValueId", "parentAddressListValueId", { unique: false });
      address3Store.transaction.oncomplete = function(event){                
          loadAddressList('address3id','Address3')           
        };
    });    

    //Town/City
    $("#addressview").find("[name='towncityid']").each(function(index){               
      townCityStore =addressDb.createObjectStore(Town_City_Store,{ keyPath: "id" });
      townCityStore.createIndex("parentAddressListValueId", "parentAddressListValueId", { unique: false });
      townCityStore.transaction.oncomplete = function(event){                     
          loadAddressList('towncityid','TownCity')           
        };
    });     

    //county
    $("#addressview").find("[name='countyid']").each(function(index){  
      countyStore =addressDb.createObjectStore(County_Store,{ keyPath: "id" });
      countyStore.createIndex("parentAddressListValueId", "parentAddressListValueId", { unique: false });
      countyStore.transaction.oncomplete = function(event){                  
          loadAddressList('countyid','County')           
        };
    });    

    //state
    $("#addressview").find("[name='stateid']").each(function(index){
      stateStore =addressDb.createObjectStore(State_Store,{ keyPath: "id" });
      stateStore.createIndex("parentAddressListValueId", "parentAddressListValueId", { unique: false });
      stateStore.transaction.oncomplete = function(event){                     
        loadAddressList('stateid','State')           
      };
    });    

    //Postal Code
    $("#addressview").find("[name='postalcodeid']").each(function(index){     
      postalCodeStore =addressDb.createObjectStore(Post_Code_Store,{ keyPath: "id" });
      postalCodeStore.createIndex("parentAddressListValueId", "parentAddressListValueId", { unique: false });
      postalCodeStore.transaction.oncomplete = function(event){                
        loadAddressList('postalcodeid','PostalCode')           
      };
    });    

    //Country 
    $("#addressview").find("[name='countryid']").each(function(index){           
      countryStore =addressDb.createObjectStore(Country_Store,{ keyPath: "id" });
      countryStore.createIndex("parentAddressListValueId", "parentAddressListValueId", { unique: false });
      countryStore.transaction.oncomplete = function(event){           
          loadAddressList('countryid','Country')           
        };
    });   

    //Region
    $("#addressview").find("[name='regionid']").each(function(index){    
      regionStore =addressDb.createObjectStore(Region_Store,{ keyPath: "id" });
      regionStore.createIndex("parentAddressListValueId", "parentAddressListValueId", { unique: false });
      regionStore.transaction.oncomplete = function(event){                    
          loadAddressList('regionid','Region')           
        };
    });

    addressDb.onversionchange = function(event) {
      alert(Address_DB_Name+' database change has occurred; you should refresh this browser window, or close it down and use the other '+ 'open version of this application, wherever it exists.');
    };       

    window.location.reload();
  }; // onupgradeneeded
 }//else
} // function openAddressDB()

function loadAddressList(fieldName,address_field) {   
    $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "/settings/address_lst_values/"+address_field,
           data: {},
           beforeSend: function() {
              $('#address_loading').show();
           },
           complete: function() {
              $('#address_loading').hide();
           },
           success: function(data, status, jqXHR)
           {                
            if (anyAjaxError(data, status, jqXHR) === false)
            { 
              //store in browser object store
              var store = getObjectStore(fieldName, 'readwrite');                                       
              for (var i in data) {                    
                store.add(data[i]);
              }                                                                              
            }                  
            $('#address_loading').hide();
           },
           error : function(jqXHR, status, errorThrown )
           {
            ajaxCallFail(jqXHR, status, errorThrown,"Error while loading "+address_field +"data")
           }              
    }); // ajax call to load address list     
}// function load address list
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause of this issue a
Calling transaction.oncomplete  after creating each object store was overriding it. So only last assigned function call was getting the executing . That was resulting only populating last object store and not the previous one.